# Why is the default capacity of ArrayList 10?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I saw the java doc for ArrayList and found that the initial capacity of ArrayList is 10.

```
 /**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
this(10);
}
```

I think it would make sense if it were any power of 2, but why 10?

I also checked HashMap's initial capacity, and it's 16 which makes sense.

```
/**
 * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
 */
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

/**
 * Constructs an empty <tt>HashMap</tt> with the default initial capacity
 * (16) and the default load factor (0.75).
 */
public HashMap() {
    this.loadFactor = DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR;
    threshold = (int)(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY * DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
    table = new Entry[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    init();
}
```

Is there any specify reason behind the number 10?

Comment: >>> _it may make sence if it would be any number of power of 2_ why?

Comment: I think it goes back to the dominant life form in cs which seem to have two manipulators with 5 digits on each. Those where used for counting in the early days of computing. Therefore they prefer powers of 10 for all kinds of things.

Comment: 10 is the initial capacity of the Array List not the size.The initial size is always 0.

Comment: @AbhisekBose : yes, you write. My mistake.Its capacity not the size. I modified the question. :)

Comment: I thought any number which is of power of 2 would be better than any random number. I don't have exact idea how its more appropriate than any other number.I thought there may be a specific reason but may be 10 is just a not too big , not too small number, to use for initial capacity.

Comment: After Java 1.7.0_40 update, ArrayList initial capacity is 0 (points to empty array)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `ArrayList` is simple growing array. When trying to add element, and the buffer size is exceeded, it is simply growing. So the initial size can be any positive value.

The 1 would be too little. Even with a few elements we will have a few resize operations.

The 100 would be a loss of space.

So, the 10 is compromise. Why 10 and not 12 or 8? First hint, that the typical use cases were analysed and this is the best fit between lost of performance and lost of space. However, I think, seeing the Sun's original code, that it wasn't analysed so deeply and it is an arbitrary 'not too small, not too big' number.

Answer (score 13):

For a List, there is no advantage in having the capacity be a power of two. In fact, there is no real advantage in any specific starting capacity. It has to be large enough to avoid multiple resizing steps for the common case of small lists, and small enough not to waste memory on unused capacity in that same case. 10 was probably chosen simply because it falls in the right range to fulfill these requirements and because it's "round".

Comment: There may be no real advantage for any specific capacity even if its of power of 2.But then, if the sun developers have done enough analysis of large amount of scenarios to find out any number, they should at least share it, may be not in the java doc but any official blog. So that everyone in opersource community have a idea and other programmers can express their views to make this initial capacity number more relavent to actual developement use cases.

Comment: @Priyank Doshi: The ideal initial capcity will be different between applications, so the average over aa large amount of scenarios would actually not be very useful - the exact value is extremely unlikely to matter for most applications, but for those where it does matter, you will want to use the best value for that specific application, not some average.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi: the answer is almost certainly that it doesn't matter enough to be worth fussing over.  10 is more or less small enough that it doesn't matter too badly if it's an overestimate, but big enough that larger `ArrayList`s will get resized up relatively quickly; worrying about details like the exact capacity is just overkill.

Comment: Generally a number which is power of 2 is prefferable choice in computer programming algos, when you are dealing with memory allocation and all that stuff. So i thought.

Comment: Java memory allocation works differently than allocation does in many other languages -- between garbage collection, object headers, and all that stuff.  It's best not to get too concerned with things like "powers-of-two" and "alignment concerns" and the like.

Answer (score 10):

`Vector`, from JDK 1.0 had a default initial capacity of 10 so it probably made some sense to remain consistent when they introduced `ArrayList` in 1.2.

Comment: No. That would be an incompatible change. The Javadoc, which is the spec, says that the default capacity is 10, so they cannot just change it.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi What I mean is that they probably wished for ArrayList to remain consistent with Vector, since they are closely related. Not referring to the other collection implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Completely arbitrary choice.

And there is no reason why power-of-2 makes any more sense here. It makes sense in a HashMap, because of how the hashing works. In fact, it *has to be* a power of two (according to the comment in the source).

Note that java.util.Vector (which is the older brother of ArrayList) also has 10.

Comment: yes, it also does have. And there may be the reason for ArrayList's capacity,too. But then the question is , why do the initial capacity of vector is 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

10 is probably a more or less arbitrary number for the default number of elements.

Comment: I don't think the sun developers are mad enough to use any random number as default number without much thinking. They must have thought of some useful and efficient scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a comment in the code, we'll never know for sure.  However, I imagine that at some point a Sun engineer has gathered statistics on ArrayList usage over a large number of real-world applications, and determined ... empirically ... that 10 gave roughly the best results on average.  (That's how they tune things like this, the optimizer, the bytecode design and so on.)

And, and others pointed out, there is no computational advantage (or disadvantage) in using a size that is a power of two for the size of an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayList is just an Array which can grow automatically..**

> Yes..the default size is 10

and I think that there's not much thinking behind this initial/default value.The default value 10 just seems not loo large and also not too small.(May be this could be reason).
What if you exceed the default initial capacity of the array..?
The next capacity for the array is calculated by-

```
New capacity=(current capacity*3)/2+1
So next size would be (10*3)/2+1= 16
And next (16*3)/2+1= 25
And So on...
```