# Default initial capacity of ArrayList and HashMap unequal

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the default capacity of ArrayList is 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794890/why-is-the-default-capacity-of-arraylist-is-10)

Why are the default initial capacities of `ArrayList` and `HashMap` unequal?

- Default Initial Capacity of `ArrayList` : 10
- Default Initial Capacity of `HashMap` : 16

Also `HashMap` capacity is a power of two but not for `ArrayList`. This is as per JDK6.

Comment: Any specific reason why they *should* be equal?

Comment: Both grow dynamically..so why not have same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashMap uses an array which MUST have a size which is a power of 2 (as per the documentation). So I guess they chose the initial capacity that was the lowest value that is at least equal to the initial capacity of an ArrayList.

And these two numbers were also probably chosen based on statistics on actual programs, in order to have the best tradeoff between performance and memory consumption.

You can only guess, unless Josh Bloch comes in and explains us why these numbers were chosen when the collections framework was designed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment in the source of HashMap, it has to be a power of two. It makes sense in a HashMap, because of how the hashing works.

However, there is no reason why power of two makes sense in an arraylist. If there was any reason behind choosing such a number, it would have been mentioned in the source itself.

IMHO, it is just an arbitrary number, large enough to avoid frequent resizing(better performance) and small enough not to waste memory on unused capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The initial capacity of ArrayList depends on the JVM implementation (i.e. there is no official requirements for this value). So you may have 10 or 16, it depends on the JVM you are using.