# Declaring initial capaity for a list in java is a bad technique?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

I have multiple ArrayLists with the same capacity. I fill these lists by reading a file.

I know that one difference between an Array and an ArrayList is that the Array have a fixed capacity while the ArrayList have a variable capacity. You should explicitly specify the array length when you declare it, but the ArrayList re-size itself when gets full.

Any resize operation in ArrayList will slow down performance as it involves creating new Array and copying content from old array to new array. Becouse of this I am thinking to:

A - explicitly initialize the rest of ArrayList's with the capacity of first, so these lists will not have to resize themselves and copy the old array elements to the new one or,

B - I can renounce at rest of lists, I only declare the first list and the rest will be Arrays with the length of the ArrayList.

Example:

A:

```
static ArrayList<ObjectType> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ObjectType> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1.size());
ArrayList<ObjectType> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1.size());
...
```

B:

```
static ArrayList<ObjectType> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ObjectType[] array1 = new  ObjectType[list1.size()]; 
ObjectType[] array2 = new  ObjectType[list1.size()];
ObjectType[] array3 = new  ObjectType[array1.length];
...
```

The questions are:

Is the A example a bad programming technique? But the B example?

Which example is better to be used?

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is at all. What goes into `list1`?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you could simple use `ArrayList<>(list1);` which will take a copy of `list1`.  The reason to provide any sizing information to the `ArrayList` is to improve performance when it nears capacity. Neither are good or bad, they both accomplish the same thing, but `ArrayList` is dynamic, meaning it can grow...

Comment: How do you know how many extra lists you need? If you know that number, why don't you just initialize your original list with that capacity?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis:  I said that I am reading elements from a file. First, I add elements in list1. The capacity of next listh will be equal with the capacity of list1. So, the elements that I subsequently add in the next lists will not have to be coppied in the new resized ArrayList after it resized itself becouse it was completely filled. ForTheonewhodeletedthecomment: The first capacity of an ArrayList is not 0, but a positive number : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794890/why-is-the-default-capacity-of-arraylist-10)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I know how many extra list I need becouse I know what kind of elements I am looking for in the file that I read. That was not the question....

Comment: Don't confuse capacity with size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an ArrayList with an initial capacity is not a bad technique at all. In fact it's going to give you a much better performance since it doesn't have to reallocate memory and copy the existing contents everytime the size is full while you keep adding elements to the list.

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html),

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at
>   least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an
>   ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth
>   policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has
>   constant amortized time cost.
>
> An application can increase the capacity of an ArrayList instance
>   before adding a large number of elements using the ensureCapacity
>   operation. This may reduce the amount of incremental reallocation.

Comment: Which example do you think is better? I think that if I specify the initial capacity to subsequently lists will work exactly as the arrays in the B example in terms of memory allocation.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is also an array implementation only behind the scenes. When you consider memory allocation, using an `ArrayList` may use a very small constant memory higher than an array. But you have many benefits like adding and removing elements easily. So, I would go with ArrayList implementation.

Comment: Indeed, I have many benefits using lists, and the code is clearer. I will initialize the capacity of subsequently lists. Thank you all for posts!

Answer (score 0):

The only time I set the initial size of a List is when I am certain I know how many elements that list is going to contain.  In the example below, there will exactly the same number of elements in stuffNames than the original stuffList. So, we prevent the need for the list to self-expand as we add to it.

Good:

```
    List<Stuff> stuffList = getStuff();
    List<String> stuffNames = new ArrayList<String>( stuffList.size() );
    for (Stuff stuff : stuffList) {
        stuffNames.add( stuff.getName() );
    }
```

But in this example, we don't always add the name, depending on hasNiceName() - so in this case we created a list with capacity larger than possibly required.

Bad:

```
    List<Stuff> stuffList = getStuff();
    List<String> stuffNames = new ArrayList<String>( stuffList.size() );
    for (Stuff stuff : stuffList) {
        if (stuff.hasNiceName()) {
            stuffNames.add( stuff.getName() );
        }
    }
```

But, for my Good example, it depends if you even consider this a code smell and that the self-expanding List is irrelevant to the developer.